# How to combine objects with same filed value in spark

Tags: join, apache-spark, rdd, reduce

My Device Class defined below:

```
case class Device(imei: String, mac: String, idfa: String, idfv: String)
```

If any field of two Device is equal, there are treated as Same Device. There is a  RDD with billion objects: deviceRDD: RDD[Device]

I want to combine all same Device use combine function

```
def combine(a: Device, b: Device): Device = {...}
```

Currently, I do

```
val step1 = deviceRDD.map(r => (r.imei, r)).filter(_._1 != "").reduceByKey(combine).
union(deviceRDD.filter(_.imei == "")
val step2 = step1.map(r => (r.mac, r)).filter(_._1 != "").reduceByKey(combine).
union(deviceRDD.filter(_.mac== "")
val step3 = step2.map(r => (r.idfa, r)).filter(_._1 != "").reduceByKey(combine).
union(deviceRDD.filter(_.idfa== "")
val step4 = step3.map(r => (r.idfv, r)).filter(_._1 != "").reduceByKey(combine).
union(deviceRDD.filter(_.idfv== "")
```

But it need 4 times reduceByKey, and

Is there any better way to do it?

Maybe the key is to create a appropriate Partitioner to partitioning "equal" Device objects into same partition?

Comment: why don't you create normal(not case class) scala class and override equals?

Comment: After normal class created and override equals,  how to combine/reduce equal objects ?

Comment: rdd.reduceByKey(combine)

Comment: What is the key and value?